# jquery Drag and Drop pep: how can i find my Object coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

**Hello!**

Im Using Jquery pep for Drag and Drop.

I can make it draggable but i don't know how to get the current position of the object..

**Here is my code:**

```
var options = {
            cssEaseDuration: 1000
           start:          function(ev,obj){ $('#title').text('Start!'); },
           drag:           function(ev,obj){ 
           console.log("we're dragging!");
          // **I have to know here the coordinates**
           },
           rest:           function(ev,obj){ 
console.log("stopped!"); 

 }
            };


       rectangle.pep(options);
```

**Here is the Demo Page:**
http://pep.briangonzalez.org/demo

(you can see in this page, in Debug mode, you can see the coordinates - bottom right - but i cant use it)

**Full info:**
http://www.wwvalue.com/web-design/jquery/kinetic-drag-with-jquery-css3-and-html5.html

**Thank you very much for your help!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution, Very simple:

```
var Drag1 = sym.$("Drag1");
var drag = $(Drag1).position();
console.log('x: ' + drag.left + 'y: ' + drag.top);
```

Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).mousemove(function(e){
      console.log(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
   }); 
})
```

Full documentation here: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

Comment: Thanks! the code is Working, But i need the current position of the Object and not Only the mouse position...